# Delete Rows selected in a python GUI treeview and then have it deleted from sqlite3 database as well

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

I am using tkinter. I have a treeview and I am displaying data in the treeview from a database from SQlite DB. However, I added a delete function to be able to select values from the treeview and then delete them with the delete function and button. It deletes from the treeview but it doesn't delete from the database.

```
def delete():
name2 = name_1.get()
phone2 = phone_number.get()
conn2 = sq.connect('Clients.db')
c2 = conn2.cursor()
selected_item = tree1.selection_set()
query = "DELETE FROM clients WHERE name=? AND phone=?"
c2.execute(query,(selected_item,))
conn2.commit()
tree1.delete(selected_item)






root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.title("Hello")
root.configure(background="powder blue")
header = Label(root, text = "Clients Database",    font=("arial",30,"bold")).pack()

con = sq.connect('Clients.db')
c = con.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (name TEXT, phone TEXT)")
con.commit


tree1 = ttk.Treeview(root, height=10, columns=("Name", "PhoneNumber"),   show=["headings"])
tree1.column('Name', anchor=W)
tree1.column('PhoneNumber', anchor=W)
tree1.heading('Name', text="Name")
tree1.heading('PhoneNumber', text="Phone Number")
```

I get the same error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/home/zizibaby/Desktop/Ingredients .py", line 38, in delete
c2.execute(query,(selected_item,))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The  current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Comment: Your query expects the `name` and `phone` to the specified but you are only providing 1 argument which will be tree item. Use `selected_item` to get the name and phone from the current row and pass those values to the query on the `c2.execute` line

Comment: Do I pass name and phone as arguments in the [selected_item] in order to get the nae and phone from the current row?

Comment: I tried just passing name and phone but that only provided me with the error of not having enough parameters in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious on why you are using `selected_item = tree1.selection_set()`.

From the docs:

> selection_set(*items)
>
> items becomes the new selection.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: items can be passed as separate arguments, not
>   just as a single tuple.

It looks to me you should be using `tree.selection()` instead.